# Hand gesture controlled car with ultrasonic sensor (obstacle avoiding) code is not working as it should work

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

I am working on a project in which I am making a hand gesture controlled car with three ultrasonic sensors, so here is the code I wrote but the code is not working as it should work. The left, right or front sensor should when having the distance between it and obstacle less than 6cm it should dodge the obstacle accordingly but it is not working like that, instead it goes backward and stops the repeats this again and again.

Basically, this code should work as following:

1. Take input from the HT12D
2. Check if pin 10, pin 11, pin 12 or pin 13 is high or low, i.e., 1 or 0
3. Arduino will take this input and will make the decision accordingly.

Here's the code:

```
#include <NewPing.h>
#define Q0 0//connect pin 10 of HT12D to arduino D0
#define Q1 1//connect pin 11 of HT12D to arduino D1
#define Q2 2//connect pin 12 of HT12D to arduino D2
#define Q3 3//connect pin 13 of HT12D to arduino D3
#define TRIGGER_PIN 4//connect trigpin of ultrasonic sensor 1 to arduino D4
#define TRIGGER_PIN1 5//connect trigpin of ultrasonic sensor 2 to arduino D5
#define TRIGGER_PIN2 6//connect trigpin of ultrasonic sensor 3 to arduino D6
#define ECHO_PIN 7//connect echopin of ultrasonic sensor 1 to arduino D7
#define ECHO_PIN1 8//connect echopin of ultrasonic sensor 2 to arduino D8
#define ECHO_PIN2 9//connect echopin of ultrasonic sensor 3 to arduino D9
#define P1 10//connect D10 of arduino to pin 2 of L293D
#define P2 11//connect D11 of arduino to pin 7 of L293D
#define P3 12//connect D12 of arduino to pin 15 of L293D
#define P4 13//connect D13 of arduino to pin 10 of L293D
#define MAX_DISTANCE 200//Maximum distance we want to ping (in cm)
long duration, distance, RightSensor, FrontSensor, LeftSensor;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin (9600);
pinMode(TRIGGER_PIN, OUTPUT);
pinMode(ECHO_PIN, INPUT);
pinMode(TRIGGER_PIN1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(ECHO_PIN1, INPUT);
pinMode(TRIGGER_PIN2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(ECHO_PIN2, INPUT);
pinMode(Q0, INPUT);
pinMode(Q1, INPUT);
pinMode(Q2, INPUT);
pinMode(Q3, INPUT);
pinMode(P1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(P2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(P3, OUTPUT);
pinMode(P4, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() 
{ 
NewPing sonar(TRIGGER_PIN, ECHO_PIN);//pings fornt sensor
RightSensor = distance;
NewPing sonar1(TRIGGER_PIN1, ECHO_PIN1);//pings right sensor
LeftSensor = distance;
NewPing sonar2(TRIGGER_PIN2, ECHO_PIN2);//pings left sensor
FrontSensor = distance;

Serial.print(LeftSensor);
Serial.print(" - ");
Serial.print(FrontSensor);
Serial.print(" - ");
Serial.println(RightSensor);
if(RightSensor>5 && LeftSensor>5 && FrontSensor>5)//if the bot is in safe zone then
  {
    if(Q0==1 && Q1==0 && Q2==1 && Q3==0)
    forward_();
    else if(Q0==0 && Q1==1 && Q2==0 && Q3==1)
     backward_();
    else if(Q0==1 && Q1==0 && Q2==0 && Q3==1)
     right_();
    else if(Q0==0 && Q1==1 && Q2==1 && Q3==0)
     left_(); 
  }
else if(FrontSensor<=5)
 {
   if(LeftSensor>5 && RightSensor<5)
   {
    backward_();
    delay(250);
    left_();
    delay(500);
   }
   else if(RightSensor>5 && LeftSensor<5)
   {
   backward_();
   delay(250);
   right_();
   delay(500);
   }
   else if(RightSensor<5 && LeftSensor<5)
   {
   backward_();
   delay(250);
   stop_();
   delay(500);
 }
}
else if(LeftSensor<=5)
 {
  right_();
  delay(250);
  backward_();
  delay(500);
 }
else if(RightSensor<=5)
{
  left_();
  delay(250);
  backward_();
  delay(500);
}

}

void stop_()
{
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("STOP");
  digitalWrite(P1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(P2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(P3,LOW);
  digitalWrite(P4,LOW);
}
void forward_()
{
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("FORWARD");
  digitalWrite(P1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(P2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(P3,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(P4,LOW);
}
void backward_()
{
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("BACKWARD");
  digitalWrite(P1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(P2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(P3,LOW);
  digitalWrite(P4,HIGH);
}
void left_()
{
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("LEFT");
  digitalWrite(P1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(P2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(P3,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(P4,LOW);
}
void right_()
{
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("RIGHT");
  digitalWrite(P1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(P2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(P3,LOW);
  digitalWrite(P4,HIGH);
}
```

Comment: Is this about detecting hand gestures or obstacles? Please focus the question and create an [mcve] by leaving everything else out.

Comment: actually, the problem is that the bot is not able to detect obstacles, it only goes back and stops and the repeats, instead it should take input and avoid the obstacles

Answer (score 1):

You are never actually measuring the distance, which causes all of Right/Front/Left-Sensor to be < 5.

Where it goes wrong in your code:

```
NewPing sonar(TRIGGER_PIN, ECHO_PIN);//pings fornt sensor
RightSensor = distance;
```

The variable 'distance' is declared, but never assigned a value. I'm surprised you don't get a compilation error.

According to the documentation for the NewPing library (read it [here](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/NewPing) - please do!):

First create a NewPing object. You got that sort of right - `NewPing sonar(TRIGGER_PIN, ECHO_PIN);`. However, this is not 'doing a ping', this is creating an object you can use to make a ping. Therefor you should do this in `void setup()`. You only have to create the sonar once (well, 3 times once that is: front, left and right), and then ping that same object every time.

Next, in the `void loop()` you can get a measurement with `RightSensor = sonar.ping_cm();` This pings the sensor and returns the distance in centimeters.